# Dismissing SKStoreReviewController in UiTest

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uitest, skstorereviewcontroller

In my Xamarin Forms app, I'm using the SKStoreReviewController to display a review modal for rating my app, but in the UI tests, I want to be able to dismiss it.  However, app.Tap("Not Now") does not work.  Is there a way to easily dismiss it from the UITests?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try `app.Repl()` and run `app.Query("Not Now").Any()` to see if this control really exist.

- You can also debug the Test.
- Use try catch to check if there is any error.
- You can also use AutomationID to identify that control
  directly.